# What do I do with the Silence Rod/Flame Rod in King's Field 2?

Tags: kings-field-2

The gravedigger in the Ancient Battleground says that the Silence Rod and the Flame Rod form a powerful pair. I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean. I have both weapons--the silence rod, as near as I can tell is just a melee weapon, and the flame rod casts a free fireball, which is a little neat I guess, but doesn't replace the fire spells I already have access to. Is there an NPC I need to go to to combine these weapons? Is there a way to wield both weapons at once? I'm confused as to what makes these weapons so great.

Answer (score -1):

The silence rod 1 hits some monsters, ghosts, scythe wielding headless skeletons, ect. I'm not too sure about the flame rod, but a assume that it does similar things. You can't combine them or duel wield.